# Is it safe to disable log_checkpoints in postgres 15?

Tags: postgresql, postgres15

I've noticed that Postgres 15 has checkpoint enabled by default, and I'm curious about the rationale behind this decision, especially since it appears to be filling the log file with checkpoint messages and also is it safe to disable?

Reason and Is it safe to disable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason can be seen from the [commit message](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commit;h=64da07c41a8c0a680460cdafc79093736332b6cf) and the [linked discussion](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CALj2ACX-rW_OeDcp4gqrFUAkf1f50Fnh138dmkd0JkvCNQRKGA%40mail.gmail.com). Remember that PostgreSQL is open source. The decision was not unanimous, but I think that two log message every five minutes are not too much, and I have got valuable clues from these messages in the past.

However, it is totally safe to disable `log_checkpoints`.

Comment: Thanks @Laurenz for quick response: I see that the messages are not every 5 minutes in log.  2023-09-27 19:13:58 2023-09-27 13:43:58.426 UTC [199] LOG:  checkpoint starting: time
2023-09-27 19:13:58 2023-09-27 13:43:58.903 UTC [199] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 5 buffers
2023-09-27 19:18:59 2023-09-27 13:48:59.005 UTC [199] LOG:  checkpoint starting: time
2023-09-27 19:18:59 2023-09-27 13:48:59.457 UTC [199] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 
2023-09-27 19:23:58 2023-09-27 13:53:58.551 UTC [199] LOG:  checkpoint 
2023-09-27 19:23:58 2023-09-27 13:53:58.978 UTC [199] LOG:  checkpoint

Comment: Then you either have a different setting for `checkpoint_timeout`, or your `may_wal_size` is too low, and you get way too many checkpoints. If the latter is your problem, increase `max_wal_size` (and be grateful to `log_checkpoints` that it gave you the clue).

Comment: Let me check max_wal_size, I will check and comeback.

Comment: That looks like every 5 minutes to me.

Comment: yeah, you are right, Thank you for your input.